# Terraform `for_each` On `map(map(object{}))` Not Finding Object Attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

## Problem Statement

I'm getting an unexpected error with my terraform code given my current understanding of how to iterate on values in Terraform. I would love for someone to point out how I am setting this up incorrectly and why my for_each loop isn't able to access the objects attributes as expected.

## Error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on lambda.tf line 58, in module "push_lambdas":
│   58:     each.value.environment_variables,
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 1 attribute "dev-main"
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "environment_variables".
```

## example.tf

```
module "push_lambdas" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.lambda_configs[var.env_name] : k => v }
  source   = "../../modules/lambda-v2"
  providers = {
    aws = aws
  }

  enable_replica = false
  env_name       = var.env_name
  function_name  = "${var.env_name}-${each.key}"
  package_type   = "Image"
  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${module.defaults.aws_account_id}:role/${var.env_name}-${each.key}-role"
  timeout  = 600
  environment = merge(
    each.value.environment_variables,
    tomap({
      ENV_NAME  = var.env_name
    })
  )
  dead_letter_config = aws_sns_topic.finalized_rates_replication_topic.arn
  # TODO: Leaving myself a note here to add VPC configuration
}
```

## vars.tf

```
variable "lambda_configs" {
  #type    = map(map(object({
  #  memory = optional(number),
  #  timeout = optional(number),
  #  ephemeral_storage = optional(number),
  #  environment_variables = map(string),
  #  subnets = optional(list(string))
  #})))
  type = any
  default = {
    dev-main = {
      "replication" = {
        memory = 128
        timeout = 120
        ephemeral_storage = 512
        environment_variables = {
          LOG_LEVEL     = "DEBUG",
          # lots of stuff here
        }
        # TODO: Figure out where these are derived and if we can import them.
        subnets = ["some_subnets"]
      }
      "test-generator" = {
        dev-main = {
          memory = 128
          timeout = 120
          ephemeral_storage = 512
          environment_variables = {
            LOG_LEVEL     = "WARNING",
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dev-qa = {
      "replication" = {
        memory = 128
        timeout = 120
        ephemeral_storage = 512
        environment_variables = {
          LOG_LEVEL     = "DEBUG",
          # lots of stuff here
        }
        subnets = ["some_subnets"]
      }
      "test-generator" = {
        dev-main = {
          memory = 128
          timeout = 120
          ephemeral_storage = 512
          environment_variables = {
            LOG_LEVEL     = "WARNING",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var.lambda_configs` has **inconsistent** structure. That's why it fails. When you access `replication`, `environment_variables` can be accessed as:

```
each.value.environment_variables
```

However, when you access `test-generator`,  `environment_variables` must be accessed as:

```
each.value.dev-main.environment_variables
```

Comment: Upon further inspection `      "test-generator" = {
        dev-main = {` is the core issue. I just removed the second `dev-main` portion after I realized I failed to delete this part. This is me being sloppy after deciding to change the structure.